# Immigration at port of arrival: By whom was passage paid? S.COL.23

Tags: immigration

While researching port of arrival immigration forms from the SS Bremen out of Bremen Germany in 1927, some entries have the code S.COL.23 as the answer to the 
"By whom was passage paid?" question.

[image]

Any idea what this means?

Update: Doh, the comment by @J.J.D. that says "See Column 23" is correct, that column is "Whether going to join a relative or friend; and if so, what relative or friend, and his name and complete address". If you restate your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Is this immigration to the US, or somewhere else? Either way which port or do you mean that this is immigration into Bremen?

Comment: Could it mean 'See column 23' ? Hard to see without the whole document.

Comment: @PolyGeo FYI there are steamships named after the cities where the ports are, a lovely trap for the drowsy researcher.  

In order to answer this question, I'd like to know what passenger list this is from -- a page number would be a bonus. We don't need the name of a passenger to answer the question, but it would be useful to see the entire page so we could see the notation in context and be able to read the headers.  A simple citation of the arrival would suffice -- we don't need the entire page inlined.

Comment: @J.J.D. Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could mean 'See column 23'.